# Getting emr-ddb-hadoop.jar to connect DynamoDB with EMR Spark

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table that I need to connect to EMR Spark SQL to run queries on the table. I got the EMR Spark Cluster with release label emr-4.6.0 and Spark 1.6.1 on it.

I am referring to the document: [Analyse DynamoDB Data with Spark](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1G4SQRV049UL0/Analyze-Your-Data-on-Amazon-DynamoDB-with-Apache-Spark)

After connecting to the master node, I run the command:

```
spark-shell --jars /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar
```

It gives a warning:

```
Warning: Local jar /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar does not exist, skipping.
```

Later, when I import the DynamoDB Input Format using

`import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat`

It gives the error:

```
 error: object dynamodb is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop
     import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat
 error: object dynamodb is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop
     import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat
```

I think it is the jar that is causing this error. Where do I get this emr-ddb-hadoop.jar?

Answer (score 3):

don't use spark-shell --jars, configuration in spark-default.cnf:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath  /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar
```

Later, import the DynamoDB Input Format is OK

```
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, typically the location of said configuration file is /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of this problem is that emr-ddb-hadoop.jar is not available in the environment (or the location specified). In oder to install the dynamo DB libraries you have to select Hadoop 2.7.2 along with your applications of interest when you are creating the spark EMR cluster. Did you select that ?

If not launch a new cluster, go to advanced options and make sure Hadoop 2.7.2 is selected along with other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `/usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar` will not exist on EMR launch. You should install the necessary bigtop package first:

`sudo yum install -y /var/aws/emr/packages/bigtop/emr-ddb/noarch/emr-ddb-hadoop-3.0.0-1.amzn1.noarch.rpm`

Notice, probably another package version may be present - check content of the `/var/aws/emr/packages/bigtop/emr-ddb/noarch/` directory.